# Exact difference between Ext.panel.Panel and Ext.Panel in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
        var childPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
           html: 'First Panel'
        });
        var childPanel2 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
           html: 'Another Panel'
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
           renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
           width: 100,
           height : 100,
           border : true,
           frame : true,
           items: [ childPanel1, childPanel2 ]
        });
     });
```

I have above code, and I want to know what does the `Ext.Panel` and `Ext.panel.Panel` do and what are the differences between them if both are not same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have same purpose, but [`Ext.Panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.Panel.html) is modern toolkit class of panel, while [`Ext.panel.Panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) is classic toolkit class of panel.You can't run modern toolkit class in classic toolkit and vice versa. Only reason you can run your code in both toolkits without errors is that there is a property  `alternateClassName` in both codes of these classes, which for `Ext.Panel` is `Ext.panel.Panel` and vice versa. You can check it below:
[`code of Ext.Panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/src/Panel.js-4.html)
[`code of Ext.panel.Panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Panel.js-7.html)

And what about real differences, you can check `configs`, `properties`, `methods`, `events`, `theme variables` and `theme mixins` of both classes.

Comment: This is wrong. Both modern and classic have aliases for panel, so classic has both AND modern has both. The names are just aliases.

Comment: This is right @beso9595 ! One for `classic` and other for `modern` toolkit.

Comment: Its not "only" about aliases.

Comment: It is only about aliases, as you noted they use `alternateClassName` to define multiple names for the same class. Not sure why this answer got accepted, it's just flat out wrong.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. Ext has functionality built in to the class system to have aliases for class names:

`console.log(Ext.panel.Panel === Ext.Panel);`